# Display different store's data in a single xtemplte

Tags: html, extjs, model, sencha-touch-2

I have  two stores and their corresponding Models...

**Poll Model**

```
Ext.define('PollsTest.model.Poll', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
xtype : 'poll', 

requires: [
    'Ext.data.identifier.Uuid'
],


config: {
    fields: [
        { name: 'title'},
        { name: 'uri' },


    ],
    identifier: {
                type: 'uuid'
            },
    hasMany :
            [
                {
                    model : 'PollsTest.model.Choice',
                    name : 'Choices',
                    primaryKey : 'title',
                    foreignKey : 'title',
                    foreignStore : 'Choices'
                }
            ]

}


});
```

**Choice Model**

```
    Ext.define('PollsTest.model.Choice', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

   requires: [
        'Ext.data.identifier.Uuid'
    ],


    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'choice', type: 'auto' },
            { name: 'votes', type: 'auto' },
            {name : 'title', type: 'auto'},
            {name : 'uri', type : 'auto'}

        ],

      identifier: {
                    type: 'uuid'
                }, 

    belongsTo : {
                        model : 'PollsTest.model.Poll',
                        name : 'Choices',
                        primaryKey : 'title',
                        foreignKey : 'title',
                        foreignStore : 'Choices',
                        getterName: 'getChoice',
                        setterName: 'setChoice'

                }        
    }



    });
```

and I have to Display in my template in such a manner that,

```
'<p>{title} <br> choices : {uri}<br></p>',
'<tpl for "choices">',                      
'<p> {Choice.choice} <br></p>',
'</tpl>',
```

and now I'm not getting any errors but the choice is not displaying in the template.
The template is is a panel not in a List.

Any thoughts will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a single object by manipulating both stores and then that object can be used to render data in the template. I am not sure if there is any other way of doing this.

Comment: How can i create a single object by manipulate both stores?? Can you provide Any working examples/ codes ??

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a [DataView](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.View), and learning how to use [XTemplates](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate).

This can be accomplished by using the XTemplate custom helper functions, assuming the data is already joined or doesn't require some sort of asynchronous call.